# While uploading a new version of TFS extension, it stuck in "verifying" step

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-extensions

I was developing a local extension on TFS 2018. I uploaded the new versions of it several times. But this time after I uploaded the new version of it on the marketplace, I tried to upload it on TFS (https://mytfsserver/_gallery/manage). While uploading it, I got a network interruption and it stuck on "verifying" step for hours.

I tried to remove the extension and install again. Also, I created new versions and tried to upload them but it doesn't work for me.
Please let me know what should I do to pass this step.

Verifying message:

[image: Verifying message]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description that might be a **validation** in marketplace side.

> *To upload an extension to the Marketplace:*
>
> 1.Navigate to the Visual Studio Marketplace Publishing Portal
>
> 2.Find the Upload new extension button, navigate to your packaged .vsix file, and select upload.
>
> 3.After a quick validation, your extension will appear in the extensions list:

Please wait some time and check again if it get verified or refused.

Besides, if you do not want your extension to be published to marketplace, you could also give a try with [unpublish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/publish/overview?view=tfs-2018#unpublish) first then upload it to TFS gallery which may do the trick.

If above ways still not solve the issue, just try to clean the client caches (including both TFS and Browser), then test it again.

TFS:

```
C:\Users\{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\{version}\Cache
```

Browser, IE for example (based on your settings) :

```
C:\Users\{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Uploading extension was successful for my case, the problematic issue was the uploading my local extension to the TFS. I also tried to clean the cache directories that you mentioned, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Sennur This is really weird. I have created a simple test, even after upload extension to marketplace, you should also be able to upload to local TFS. Did this only occur for this specific extension, have you tried another extension. Also you could unpublish the extension from marketplace and try to upload to TFS again, which may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searches, we found that one of tfs windows services is stopped. After restarting it the problem is solved. @PatrickLu, thank you for your help. 
I hope this would be useful for the other people who have same problem.

Comment: could you please elaborate which service was stopped?